# values not visible clearly in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the help of following code I am plotting a graph; however, the values are not clearly visible; they are mixed with graph:

```
for x111,y1 in zip(x1,loss_list):
    plt.text(x111, y1, '%.2f' % y1, ha='right', va= 'bottom', color='blue')
for x112,y2 in zip(x1,val_loss_list):
    plt.text(x112, y2, '%.2f' % y2, ha='left', va= 'top', color='orange')
plt.plot(xc,train_loss_history)
plt.plot(xc,val_loss_history)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
#plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'])
plt.show()
```

where x111 and other values and list i got from my code. and getting following plot
[image]

how to make the visualization more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe tweak the alpha values (transparencies) of the colors used?

something like this maybe?

```
for x111,y1 in zip(x1, loss_list):
    plt.text(x111, y1, '%.2f' % y1, ha='right', va='bottom', color='blue')
for x112,y2 in zip(x1, val_loss_list):
    plt.text(x112, y2, '%.2f' % y2, ha='left', va='top', color='black')  # changed to black, but you can try some other color to see if you like it better
plt.plot(xc, train_loss_history, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xc, val_loss_history, color='orange', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
#plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train', 'val'])
plt.show()
```

You did not provide data, so it is hard to tweak the values to maximize readability.

Comment: I know how to accept. right now trying for other solution mention above

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of your text and also the size: `size='x-small'`

```
for x111,y1 in zip(x1,loss_list):
    plt.text(x111, y1, '%.2f' % y1,color='black',horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom')
for x112,y2 in zip(x1,val_loss_list):
    plt.text(x112, y2, '%.2f' % y2,color='black',horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='bottom')
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. My solution is not pretty, but works if you

- don't have too many values
- don't need to do it dynamically, i.e. you only have this one dataset

Hopefully someone might have a nicer, dynamic solution for you as well, but this might at least solve your problem for now.

The solution is to simply add an y-offset to each point. E.g.

```
y1_offsets = [1., 2., -2.3, 4., ...]  # Define this by hand so it looks good

for x111, y1, yoff in zip(x1,loss_list, y1_offsets):
    plt.text(x111, y1 + yoff, '%.2f' % y1, ha='right', va= 'bottom', color='blue')
```

If you need to do this dynamically, one approach could be to look at the y-values "close" to where you are plotting, and pick something appropriate. E.g. a simple "max pooling" of the y-values with a suitable window size.

Comment: I think this is the most obvious solution, which probably most people will end up with. If you feel that the numbers loose visual connection to their data points with increasing offset, you could additionally use `annotate` instead of `text`. It provides an additional line or arrow between numbers and data points.

Comment: @Hannes Ovren i diidn't understand

Comment: @SpghttCd good point with using `annotate()`. Another (simpler) option to increase the connection between label and data point is to have the values marked as "dots" in the line plot.

Comment: @Hitesh Exactly what didn't you understand? You add an offset value to each text label to move it up or down as appropriate to not be obscured by the graph.

Comment: ok. but what if my labels are large in quantity like 100. So do i have to mention 100 offset manually.

Comment: Yes, you would, which is why I mentioned that it is a bad idea if you have many points. Either try to do it automatically using the idea I outlined in the end, or use some completely different technique.